# add an apt repository only for few packages (or mirror them)

Tags: debian, apt, repository, reprepro, apt-mirror

I'd like to install a couple of packages available from an unofficial repository, problem is the repository share many packages and an apt upgrade would replace many of the official.

I know about pinning but would prefer not to use it.

I think to remember something about adding a repository for only a package, did a little search online and into apt's documentation but found not much, did also some test without success, if there's a syntax to add only few packages from a repository that would be perfect.

Alternatively I'm thinking about using cron and reprepro (or whatever is used nowadays to create a repository) to only mirror the few packages I need, anything already existing like that?

Comment: Bypass `apt`, just download the `.deb` files you want manually (usually found in `pool` in the apt repository), and install them manually with `dpkg`? If you have conflicting packages you'll have to sort out problems manually as well.

Comment: @dirkt thanks for the suggestion, not a bad idea, though I already wrote a script using wget and apt-ftparchive, seems to be working, the only thing I don't like yet is `apt-get update` trying to download many control files on the new repository, perhaps something wrong with the structure. Eventually I'll post the script once solved.

Comment: like [that](https://gist.github.com/xenogenesi/a5dc5df3c8a52a5f24d4996866b17384)